# EmberJS / Select / Content (list) / Selection / Object Equality / Compare (comparison)

Tags: ember.js, selection, equality

I have a route like this:

```
ConsultasRoute = Em.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return Em.Object.create({
      tipoClave: undefined,
      tipoConsulta: {id: 2, nombre: 'yow man'}
    });
  }
});
```

I have a controller like this:

```
ConsultasController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  tipoConsultas: [{id: 1, nombre: 'dudeee'}, {id: 2, nombre: 'yow man'}] 
});
```

And a template like this:

```
{{view 'select' content=tipoConsultas selection=model.tipoConsulta optionValue="content.id" optionLabelPath="content.nombre" prompt="Selecciona tipo consulta"}}
```

The idea is: by default the selected tipo consulta is "yow man".

But this does not work; "yow man" is not selected by default.

I think object-equality thing is in the play here. How to tell ember to do object-equality check using specific property of an object (e.g.: the "id") ?

I read about this Comparable Mixin: http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Comparable.html#method_compare maybe this can help (?). But I can't find an example of its correct use anywhere.

Can someone show me how to solve this?

---

**Added, responding to @torazaburo ( https://stackoverflow.com/a/29981303/3443096 ):**

Actually I used that approach in previous project. So I had something like this in the consultas route (let's use Consultas stuff for the sake of discussion, actually it was some other entity):

```
ConsultasRoute = Em.Route.extend({
   model: function() {
     return Em.$.ajax({
        url: 'http://myserver/userLatestConsulta?idUsuario=111',
        type: 'POST',
        ...
     }).then(function(responseJSON) {
        return Em.Object.create({
          tipoClave: undefined,
          tipoConsultaId: resposeJSON.latestTipoConsultaId
        });
     });
   }
});
```

The point is, initial tipoConsulta for this session is fetched from the backend (e.g.: the latest one used in previous session).

And the approach to initialize my select view is similar to what you described in your comment:

```
ConsultasRoute = Em.Route.extend({
  afterModel: function(consulta, transition) {
    var matchingTipoConsulta = _.find(this.controller.get('tipoConsultas'), function(tc) {
      return tc.id == consulta.tipoConsultaId; 
    });

    consulta.set('tipoConsulta', matchingTipoConsulta);
  }
});
```

But I felt like... "I shouldn't be writing these codes".... Probably there's a more concise / elegant way to do it. That's why I was looking at Comparable Mixin... (probably because my background is java prog, accustomed to overriding 'equals' method, and it usually works in situations like this). I was hoping to hear that ember "select" makes use of that mixin. Does it?

---

**UPDATE**

Confirmed: Ember does not make any use of the mixin Ember.Comparable in this situation. I tried defining an Ember.Object like this:

```
MyNamespace.TipoConsulta = Em.Object.extend(Em.Comparable, {
  id: undefined,
  nombre: undefined
});

MyNamespace.TipoConsulta.reopenClass({
  compare: function(a, b) {
    console.log('-------------- compare --------------');
    if (a.id == b.id) return 0;
    if (parseInt(a.id) < parseInt(a.id)) return -1;
    return 1;
  }
});
```

And then, redefine my catalog this way:

```
MyNamespace.tipoConsultas = [
  MyNamespace.TipoConsulta.create({id: "1", nombre: "dude"}),
  MyNamespace.TipoConsulta.create({id: "2", nombre: "yow man"})
];
```

My template:

```
{{view 'select' content=MyNamespace.tipoConsultas selection=model.tipoConsulta optionValue="content.id" optionLabelPath="content.nombre" prompt="Selecciona tipo consulta"}}
```

My route:

```
MyNamespace.ConsultasRoute = Em.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return Em.Object.create({
      tipoClave: null,
      tipoConsulta: MyNamespace.TipoConsulta.create({id: "2", nombre: "yow man"}))
    });
  }
});
```

Observations:

1. The compare method never gets invoked (clear indication Ember is not using it for this situation).
2. Worse yet, the ember select view at one point resets the tipoConsulta property of the route's model to 'null'. (I guess because it can't find the "match" in the list of tipoConsultas catalog).
3. Consequently: nothing gets selected (by default) in the dropdown box.

But, if I change my Route to this:

```
MyNamespace.ConsultasRoute = Em.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return Em.Object.create({
      tipoClave: null,
      tipoConsulta: MyNamespace.tipoConsultas[1]
    });
  }
});
```

1. The compare method is not invoked. Same as above.
2. The tipoConsulta property of the route's model doesn't get reset.
3. 'yow man' gets selected by default in the dropdown.

I think it's a pity Ember doesn't do object comparison, using the Ember.Comparable mixin in this situation.

Best regards,
Raka

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's about object equality. The `{id: 2, nombre: 'yow man'}` you are defining within the model in the route, and the lexically identical member of the array you are setting as the value of `tipoConsultas` in the controller are not "equal". They're just the "same". Ember does not do a deep comparison when looking for the selected item. However, you do not need to worry about somehow providing your own comparison function. You simply need to make sure the initially selected item **is** one of the items in the array.

There are different ways to approach this depending on the overall situation, but here's one example, initializing `tipoConsulta` in the `setupController` hook with an actual entry in `tipoConsultas`:

```
ConsultasRoute = Em.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return Em.Object.create({
      tipoClave: undefined
      // remove tipoConsulta from here
    });
  },

  // Initialize the selected item.
  // Replace firstObject with some other criteria as desired.
  setupController: function(controller, model) {
    controller.set('tipoConsulta', controller.get('tipoConultas.firstObject'));
  }
});

ConsultasController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  tipoConsultas: [{id: 1, nombre: 'dudeee'}, {id: 2, nombre: 'yow man'}],            

  // Will be set in setupController.
  tipoConsulta: null 
});
```

Comment: thanks for the response. Actually I used that approach in previous project. So I had something like this in the consultas route:
... sorry, I have to put it in my original posting section, for the code formatting.